# Converting a requests http post to tornado post request

Tags: macos, tornado, python-3.6

I have the following code:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(AUTHENTICATION_URI, data=form_data, headers=headers)
```

where form_data and headers are dictionaries of inputs. This returns correctly with a status of 200 using requests and is correct (I am able to use the session later on in my code).

I am attempting to convert this to use tornado and their http client, however when I run this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from tornado import httpclient
http_client = httpclient.HTTPClient()

response = http_client.fetch(
    httpclient.HTTPRequest(
    AUTHENTICATION_URI, method='POST', request_timeout=60, body=urlencode(form_data), headers=headers))
```

I am running into a timeout:

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout during request
```

The tornado HTTPRequest object has an optional timeout parameter, but even making that 60 seconds doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

What do I have to do differently in how I construct the tornado post request in order to recreate how I was running this using the requests http module?

Answer (score 1):

`http_client.fetch` does not return a `response`, it returns a `Future` that resolves to a response. You need to call it in an `async def` function with with `response = await http_client.fetch(...)`. You must also have started the `IOLoop`, and not be doing anything to block it. If none of this points you in the right direction, you'll need to share a more complete code sample.